# Pointers/References while using the NDK

Tags: android, pointers, reference, android-ndk

I am creating an Android app which pulls methods from a C library. One of the methods used in the C library looks like this...( Follow the pointer to `val` that was passed as the functions `second parameter`. )

```
BYTE __stdcall GetVal(WORD what, long *val){
DWORD relaydate;
BYTE tmpb;
DWORD tmpd;
WORD tmp;
#ifdef HASTHAILANDSWAP
WORD what2;
#endif  

if(val) *val=0;
if(!CheckInit()) return ERR_NOT_INIT;
if(what==VAL_NULL){
    if(RelayAPI_DataValid){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}   
if(!CheckValid()) return ERR_READ_FAIL;

switch(what){
    case VAL_SWVERSION:
        *val=RelayAPI_SWVersion;
        return 0;
    case VAL_VOLTAGE:
        *val=RelayAPI_Voltage;
        return 0;
    case VAL_VERSION:
        *val=RelayAPI_Version;
        return 0;
    case VAL_ISSMUD:
        *val=RelayAPI_isSMUD;
        return 0;
}
```

A `BYTE` is defined as an `unsigned char`. I need to call that `GetVal` method from my Java function. The functionality of my Java code should match this C code...

```
long val;
char buff[20];
if( !GetVal (VAL_SERIAL, &val) ) {}
```

And this is what I have so far in my Java Code ( I know this isn't right, I know you can't use references in Java like that, I'm just showing you what I have. ):

```
public void updateForm() {
    int val;
    char buff[];

    /**
    * SERIAL NUMBER
    */
    if( !GetVal( RelayAPIModel.VAL_SERIAL, &val ) ) { }
}
```

So, `val` is initialized as `null`(I assume, I don't know C too well), a reference to this long is passed through the function. Within the function, a pointer to `val` is assigned a value.

Is there anyway to use a method in C which is passed a reference to a NULL variable which then assigns the variable referenced a value?

EDIT :

To clarify, I am using a library which contains the GetVal method above. I am mirroring a Palm Pilot API, which is where the second code block comes from. The third code block is my call from Java, to the GetVal method in the C library.

Comment: can you post the jni wrapper function?

Comment: I'd be happy to, but what do you mean by wrapper function?

Comment: i assume that you are using jni to call native c from java? If so please post your jni code.

Comment: I'm confused as to what else you want. The GetVal function IS the native method I am calling. I have thousands of lines of JNI code I don't think it is appropriate to post it all here. If there is a specific function you would like I'll be more than happy to post it. Please look at my original post, I have edited it at the bottom to try to be clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you want the GetVal method to change a passed in parameter. Since java has no pointers you need to create a simple java class you can manipulate from within your c code.

Since i dont know your jni code i had to make a lot of guesses, so dont take the source as is. 
But it should get you on the right track.

**Java code**

```
class LongWrapper {
    private long mValue;
    public void setValue(final long value){
        mValue = value;
    }
}

native boolean GetVal(int valSerial,LongWrapper val);
```

**Example of jni code**

```
jboolean Java_com_foo_GetVal(JNIEnv *env, jint val_serial, jobject longObj)
{
    jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(longObj);
    jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "setValue", "(J)V");
    if (mid == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    jlong val=0;
    bool result = GetVal(val_serial,&val)
    env->CallLongMethod(longObj,mid, val);
    return result
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking to do. However, I am trying to pull it off without changing the C code. Is that even possible?

Comment: A Java class with a public data field would do. Less JNI plumbing that way.

Comment: @JuiCe: Java does not support primitive references, nor out parameters. So no.

Comment: @seva How would i go about avoiding the jni plumbing? Wouldn't i need to call GetFieldID and SetObjectField?

Comment: I said *less* JNI plumbing, not *none at all*. Less not by much, I admit. The field signature is not as ugly a method signature, that's about it.

Comment: @Renard Sorry but I have no experience in C. You declare the native function as GetVal, but in the C file its called Java_com_foo_GetVal, and has different parameters. How will that work? I have also decided to not change any of my C code, but instead just add a function such as the one you have above to modify my parameters to fit the GetVal function.

Comment: Java_com_foo_GetVal is the jni wrapper to your original GetVal. Just look into ndk/jni tutorials or the ndk samples to get startet